# How to switch from char * to const char *[pwm in beaglebone]?

Tags: c, embedded-linux, fopen, popen, beagleboneblack

I am working on a quadcopter project with Beaglebone.

I need help with using pwm on Beaglebone through a C program.

I have attached the following code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct pwm
{
   char period[100];
   char duty[100];
   char polarity[100];
   char run[100];
}pwm1,pwm2,pwm3,pwm4;

char pwm_1[]="P9_21";
char pwm_2[]="P9_14";
char pwm_3[]="P8_13";
char pwm_4[]="P9_42";

int initialize(struct pwm &pwmi, char pwm_i[])
{
  sprintf(path,"echo \"bone_pwm_%s\" >> /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.9/slots",pwm_i);
  fp = popen(path,"r");
  fflush(fp);
  usleep(1000);
  sprintf(path,"ls /sys/devices/ocp.3/pwm_test_%s.*/period",pwm_i);
  fp = popen(path,"r");
  while(fgets(path,100,fp)!=NULL)
      strcpy(pwmi.period,path);
  fflush(fp);
  sprintf(path,"ls /sys/devices/ocp.3/pwm_test_%s.*/duty",pwm_i);
  fp = popen(path,"r");
  while(fgets(path,100,fp)!=NULL)
      strcpy(pwmi.duty,path);
  fflush(fp);
  sprintf(path,"ls /sys/devices/ocp.3/pwm_test_%s.*/polarity",pwm_i);
  fp = popen(path,"r");
  while(fgets(path,100,fp)!=NULL)
      strcpy(pwmi.polarity,path);
  fflush(fp);
  sprintf(path,"ls /sys/devices/ocp.3/pwm_test_%s.*/run",pwm_i);
  fp = popen(path,"r");
  while(fgets(path,100,fp)!=NULL)
      strcpy(pwmi.run,path);
  fflush(fp);
  pclose(fp);
  return 0;
  printf("%s%s%s%s",pwmi.period,pwmi.duty,pwmi.polarity,pwmi.run)
}

int pwmperiod(struct pwm &pwmi, unsigned int period)
{
  sprintf(path,"echo %d > %s", period, pwm.period);
  fp = popen(path,"r");
  usleep(1000);
  pclose(fp);
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  unsigned int period = 200000;
  initialize(pwm1,pwm_1);
  initialize(pwm2,pwm_2);
  initialize(pwm3,pwm_3);
  initialize(pwm4,pwm_4);
  pwmperiod(pwm1,period);
  return 0;
}
```

Now the above code works perfectly fine. But I want to use the `pwmperiod()` function a little differently. Instead of using `popen()` all the way, I want to use `fopen()` and `fprintf()` for the function `pwmperiod()` . Something like this,

```
int pwmperiod(struct pwm &pwmi, unsigned int period)
{
  fp = fopen(pwmi.period,"r+");
  fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
  fprintf(fp,"%d",period);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

I tried the modified code but when it attempts to write the period value, it outputs "segmentation fault".

I realized that `fopen()` takes a `const char` while `pwmi.period` is just `char`. Another problem `popen()` and `sprint()` are not compatible with `const char`.

So is there a way to resolve the conversion?

Also how often is `popen()` used in C/C++ programs?

PS:
Not an expert coder and I am not from a computer science background. I am learning progressively.

Again, the code works with `popen()` perfectly. But then I am comfortable with file handling in C. So I would prefer personally `fopen()` over `popen()` . Moreover I feel it would be pointless to use `popen()` in C. Might as well use a shell script for pwm.

Comment: You can pass `char*` to arguments that request `const char*` without explicit conversion, but cannot do the opposite.

Comment: The standard `fopen()` won't take `const char`.

Comment: I realized that. But is there a way to convert from char* to const char*

Comment: There's an implicit conversion for that. `char* ptr; const char* cptr = ptr;` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside for a moment the issue of `char*` vs. `const char*` (since a `char*` can anyway be passed to any function taking a `const char*`).

Have you checked that the return value from `fopen` is non-NULL?

Note that the file must exist when `fopen` is called with `r+`. If it doesn't, `fopen` will return NULL, generating a segfault.

Since the file is only being written, not read, consider using

```
fp = fopen(pwmi.period,"w");
```

which will create a new file if one doesn't already exist.